# Dialog removes fragment from Activity before inflating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I have a funny issue, I had a `fragment` in my `activity` and all was working fine, then I introduced a `viewpager`, my goal was to have a tabbed activity which worked fine but now an issue has risen, I used to inflate a dialog in my fragment, everything would work just as expected but now when I call my dialog seems to be removing all views when it is inflated from my activity including the tabs, does anybody know why?Here is my code

```
mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(ManagerActivity.this, R.style.Material_App_BottomSheetDialog);
    parentHolder.removeAllViews();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(ManagerActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.view_scan_onclick, null);
    ViewUtil.setBackground(v, new ThemeDrawable(R.drawable.bg_window_dark));
```

Comment: parentHolder.removeAllViews(); <- this looks suspicious

Comment: thanks alot, actually at first i was using `getApplicationcontext` which kept on telling me to call `parentHolder.removeAllViews()` but after changing to `ManagerActivity.this` i forgot to remove this line, thanks alot

Comment: could you post that as a comment.

Comment: it is already comment you mean answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are getting is because removeAllViews() removes all views from layout.